# What is a rigorous way of deducing $ A \le B \le A$ from $ A-\varepsilon \le B \le A+\varepsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

**Deduction.** $ \ $ Let $A, B\in \mathbb{R}$, and suppose that, $\forall \varepsilon >0$,

$$ A-\varepsilon \le B \le A+\varepsilon.$$

Then, *since $\varepsilon$ can be chosen to be arbitrarily small $ (*)$*, we may conclude that,

$$ A \le B \le A.$$

Hence
$$ A=B.$$

---

I have used the argument $(*)$ above (in italic) several times in proofs, but it has always felt non-rigorous.

> What is a more rigorous way of deducing $ A \le B \le A$ from $ A-\varepsilon \le B \le A+\varepsilon$?

I thought of simply taking the limit $\ \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \ $ across  $ \ A-\varepsilon \le B \le A+\varepsilon$, $ $ then the result follows.  But again, I don't have any good reason why taking limits across this inequality is justified.

Comment: The sentence $\forall \epsilon > 0$ means that $\epsilon$ can be picked as small as you want, so brutally, you can pick $\epsilon = 0.000 \dots 001$. You can see that one can extend the reasoning to $\epsilon = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given inequality, $ -\varepsilon \leq B - A \leq \varepsilon $, so $|B-A| \leq \varepsilon$.  By properties of absolute values, either $|B-A| = 0$, forcing $B = A$, or $|B-A| > 0$, a contradiction of the given inequality for any positive $\varepsilon$ less than $|B - A|$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A\neq B$. Then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $|B-A|=2\epsilon$. But then $|B-A|\not\leq\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $B>A$ and let $\varepsilon=\frac12(B-A)$. Then $B>A+\varepsilon$ (since $B=A+2\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon>0$), which is impossible.

By the same argument, you can't have $B<A$. Therefore, $B=A$.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't see why the statement $B>A+\varepsilon$ is impossible from the given $\varepsilon$.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: I did **not** say that the statement $B>A+\varepsilon$ is impossible for the given $\varepsilon$. It is impossible because we are assuming that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, $B\leqslant A+\varepsilon$.